# npm project doesn't run in PowerShell but does when opened in VS Code

Tags: powershell, npm, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've pulled the PayPal standard-integration from their example GitHub.
If I open the project in VS Code and run `npm start` the server works perfectly fine without any issues for basically infinite time.

If I run `npm start` inside of a PowerShell the server just stops after a while. So my `run.ps1` file which just has this one command in it doesn't work after some time.

The application seems to run fine when opened in Powershell, there's no error or anything and most sandbox payments work fine but after a while (20 minutes+) it just stops working.

How do people usually run their npm projects? I don't believe that most users have VS Code open all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I've used

```
npm i -G
```

which installs dependencies globally and it fixed my issue.